# Convert String to BigDecimal with always two decimal places

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to convert a String to a BigDecimal.
If i run the following code with **2,6**, java converts the String always as **26**, but i want the **2.60** or if i have a String like **14,35** than it should also convert into the right German format.

```
    Locale in_ID = new Locale("de");

    DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(in_ID);
    nf.setParseBigDecimal(true);

    if(betragFruehtsueck.equals(""))
    {
        betragFruehtsueck = "0.00";
    }
    if(betragMittagessen.equals(""))
    {
        betragMittagessen = "0.00";
    }

    betragFruehtsueck = betragFruehtsueck.replace(",", ".");
    betragMittagessen = betragMittagessen.replace(",", ".");

    BigDecimal bd = null;
    BigDecimal bdM = null;

    try {
        bd = (BigDecimal) nf.parse(betragFruehtsueck);
        bdM = (BigDecimal) nf.parse(betragMittagessen);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: remove the `.replace(",", ".")` calls, because there German locale expects commas as the decimal separator. If you convert these to dots (which is the thousands separator in German), they get ignored, as you can ignore thousands separators.

Comment: And create one method that does this for a variable `value` so that you don't duplicate the exact same code for `betragFruehtsueck` (sic) and `betragMittagessen`.

Comment: And call `setScale(2)` on the parsed `BigDecimal` to get `2.60` parsed from `2,6`.

Comment: I got the output of above program as 2.6 with input as 2,6. Isn't this what you are expecting?

Comment: @S.K. No, if you take the above code, you don't get 2.6 for 2,6 - you get 26.

Answer (score 4):

Using the proper locale allows one to avoid changing decimal symbols:

```
DecimalFormat nf = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
nf.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) nf.parse("2,6");
```

And this ensures the scale of 2 is applied:

```
bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); //2.60
```

If formatting the number as string in the same locale is required, the following should work (and perhaps preferred to `bd.toString()`):

```
NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
nf2.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
//outputs "2,60"
```